# "with" keyword in Dart

Tags: dart

Could somebody please write some formal definition of keyword **with** in Dart?

In official Dart examples I have only found:

```
class TaskElement extends LIElement with Polymer, Observable {
```

But I still can't understand what is it exactly doing.

Comment: AFAIK `Observable` is redundant if you add `with Polymer` as `Polymer` already implements `Observable`, but I also just saw that this example https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#extending-dom-elements has `with Polymer, Observable`. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: It seems I was wrong - see the answer to this discussion from @MatthewButler: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/0d2tTlnYjew `with Polymer, Observable {` should be used.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The `with` keyword indicates the use of a "mixin".  See [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins).

A mixin refers to the ability to add the capabilities of another class or classes to your own class, without inheriting from those classes.  The methods of those classes can now be called on your class, and the code within those classes will execute.  Dart does not have multiple inheritance, but the use of mixins allows you to fold in other classes to achieve code reuse while avoiding the issues that multiple inheritance would cause.

I note that you have answered some questions about Java -- in Java terms, you can think of a mixin as an interface that lets you not merely specify that a given class will contain a given method, but also provide the code for that method.

Comment: This is one of the best explanations of `mixin`s out there! Thanks!

Comment: `mixin` in Dart = 'protocol' in Swift

Answer (score 19):

You can think mixin as Interface in Java and like protocol in Swift.Here is the simple example.

```
mixin Human {
  String name;
  int age;

  void about();
}

class Doctor with Human {
  String specialization;
  Doctor(String doctorName, int doctorAge, String specialization) {
    name = doctorName;
    age = doctorAge;
    this.specialization = specialization;
  }

  void about() {
    print('$name is $age years old. He is $specialization specialist.');
  }
}


void main() {
  Doctor doctor = Doctor("Harish Chandra", 54, 'child');
  print(doctor.name);
  print(doctor.age);
  doctor.about();
}
```

Hope it help to understand.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. In java an interface does not store state information and is simply a contract (with default functionality for version 1.8 and above). Here it seems that mixin `Human` is storing a state with values of `name` and `age`.

Comment: Nice example, but mixin in Dart is *not* like interfaces in Java. For example, the method in mixin doesn't have to be abstract. I think it would be better to define the body of the `about()` method in the `mixin Human` class, rather than "implement" it in the `Doctor` class, so that some confusion doesn't happen like @PiyushVishwakarma got.